# Running objcopy in CMAKE custom command causes error during make

Tags: cmake, avr

I'm trying to add a post-build command to a small project which will automatically take my build output file (ELF) and convert it to an Intel HEX format for flashing on a microcontroller.

When I add this command however, the build fails. It repeats the command with all of the CMake variable strings substituted in that is run by the shell and post-fixes it with `: not found`.

When I run that exact line in the terminal after a normal successful build of the ELF, it works as expected. Is there a gotcha I'm missing somewhere with how CMake handles this?

I've added the target to my CMakeLists.txt as follows:

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -O ihex ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}.hex"
)
```

The command ends up resolving to `<absolute-path>/avr-objcopy -O ihex test_blink.elf test_blink.hex` which I can verify since it's printed by CMake out to the terminal.

Comment: Read error message carefully: it tells that the **whole text between quotes** is invalid path. Do not put the whole *COMMAND* into double quotes, quote only a single command line argument (if needed).

Comment: FYI, AVRDUDE does support loading .elf files these days, so maybe you don't need to produce a HEX file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This string is wrong:

```
COMMAND "${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -O ihex ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}.hex"
```

You should use the `ARGS` keyword:

```
COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} ARGS -O ihex ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}.hex
```