# cannot create hex elf files with cmakelists

Tags: gcc, cmake, makefile, arm, blink

I am trying to use cmakelists to create a hex and elf file for my blinkled project, using IAR files.

The compilation is without errors with cmake but I dont see the files in the build folder.
my goal is to create a hex and elf files for flashing pursoses later on.

Can someone please tell me what I should modify to solve this problem?
thanks a lot

cmakelists:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7.2)

######################################################################
#
#   Project
#
######################################################################

project(blink_cortex_m0plus)
enable_language(ASM)

######################################################################
#
#   CPP Definitions
#
######################################################################

set(PROJECT_FLAGS_ARCH
    "-mcpu=cortex-m0plus \
     -mthumb"
)

set(PROJECT_LINKER_FLAGS
    "-Wl,-Map=${PROJECT_NAME}.map \
    -L${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../config/ \
    -Tlinker.ld"
)

set(PROJECT_C_FLAGS_WARNINGS   "${COMMON_FLAGS_WARNINGS} ${C_FLAGS_WARNINGS_EXTRA}")


######################################################################
#
#   Sources
#
######################################################################

set(PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIRS
    ${PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR}
    ${BLINK_DIR}/../
    ${CYPRESS_CORE_LIBRARY}
)

set(PROJECT_SRCS
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main_cm0plus.c
    ${CYPRESS_PERIPHERAL_DRIVERS_LIBRARY}system_tviibe1m_cm0plus.c
    ${CYPRESS_PERIPHERAL_DRIVERS_LIBRARY}startup_cm0plus.S
)

######################################################################
#
#   TARGET
#
######################################################################

set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS   "${C_FLAGS} ${C_FLAGS_WARNINGS}  ${FLAGS_OPTIMIZATION} ${PROJECT_FLAGS_ARCH}")
set (CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS "${C_FLAGS}   ${C_FLAGS_WARNINGS}   ${FLAGS_OPTIMIZATION} ${PROJECT_FLAGS_ARCH}")
#set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CXX_FLAGS} ${CXX_FLAGS_WARNINGS} ${FLAGS_OPTIMIZATION} ${PROJECT_FLAGS_ARCH}")
set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${LINKER_FLAGS} ${PROJECT_LINKER_FLAGS} ${FLAGS_OPTIMIZATION} ${PROJECT_FLAGS_ARCH}")

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-gcc)
set(OBJCOPY arm-none-eabi-objcopy)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)


include_directories(
        ${PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${CYPRESS_PERIPHERAL_DRIVERS_LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIRS}
# )


add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}.elf ${PROJECT_SRCS} ${CYPRESS_PERIPHERAL_DRIVERS_LIBRARY_SRCS})

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-Map=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/${PROJECT_NAME}.map")
set(HEX_FILE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/${PROJECT_NAME}.hex)
set(BIN_FILE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/${PROJECT_NAME}.bin)

add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}.elf POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${OBJCOPY} -Oihex $<TARGET_FILE:${PROJECT_NAME}.elf> ${HEX_FILE}
        COMMAND ${OBJCOPY} -Obinary $<TARGET_FILE:${PROJECT_NAME}.elf> ${BIN_FILE}
        COMMENT "Building ${HEX_FILE} \nBuilding ${BIN_FILE}")
```

Answer (score 1):

I convert to .bin and .hex it with the following command:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${APPLICATION}
    POST_BUILD
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    COMMAND ${OBJCOPY} ARGS -O binary ${APPLICATION} ${APPLICATION_BIN}
    COMMAND ${OBJCOPY} ARGS -O ihex -R .eeprom -R .fuse -R .lock -R .signature ${APPLICATION} ${APPLICATION_HEX}
)
```

One notable difference is the `ARGS` as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53573133